# Set NavigationBar Tint Color in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

Am trying to set the tint for all navigation bars from my appdelegate in iOS 7.  This worked always before, but for some reason now, nothing is changing.  In the didFinishLaunching part of my appDelegate I have:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:toolbarcolor];
```

However, the bar stays the default translucent option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the bar tint color using the [barTintColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor) property:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

If you also don't want the navigation bar to be translucent, you can set the [translucent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/translucent) property to NO.

Unfortunately, the translucent property is not available on the UINavigationBar appearance proxy, so you will have to set this property individually (in your storyboard, .xib, or in something like viewDidLoad in your controller).

Answer (score 3):

Swift version:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = colorBar
```

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to set bar tint color for whole application, write in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method of AppDelegate.m**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

**Following is output :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0

```
 let navigationBarAppearnce = UINavigationBar.appearance()
```

*A navigation bar’s [tintColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624937-tintcolor) affects the color of the back indicator image, button titles, and button images:*

```
navigationBarAppearnce.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

*The barTintColor property affects the color of the bar itself:*

```
navigationBarAppearnce.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.180, green: 0.459, blue: 0.733, alpha: 1.00)
```

[image]