# Why tintColor doesn't work on navigation bar or toolbar on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, modalviewcontroller

On iOS7 of iPad, first, I setup an modal view controller, the size is 320 * 460, then, in this modal view controller, I presented another navigation view controller, after this, the tint color of navigation bar and tool bar of the presented navigation controller turns gray. I have tried to set tint color of navigation bar and tool bar, but it just doesn't work.

Then I tried to present the navigation controller directly, then all tint color works both on navigation bar and tool bar.

I have tried with the `barTintColor` property of navigation bar and tool bar, it works.

I don't know what happens.

**Update**

first, I define a view controller: modalViewController
The present the modal view controller like this:

```
if (DeviceIsPad()) // DeviceIsPad is a method defined somewhere to tell that the device is an iPad.
    modaViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

//here self is a normal view controller
[self presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Second, define a navigation view controller: navigationController
Present the navigation controller like this:

```
if (DeviceIsPad())
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

// here self means the modalViewController mentioned above
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I setup the navigation bar and toolbar bar items in 'viewDidLoad' method of navigationController.

By default, when the navigation view controller comes out, all toolbar button items(The items are built with just basic title like `Cancel`, `OK`) turns to be gray.

At the same time, I have tried to set `tintColor` of `tool bar` and `navigation bar`. Both instance method and appearance method(like `[[UIToolBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]]`) are used. But it still doesn't work.

And then I tried to present the `navigationViewController` mentioned above with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style directly from a normal view controller, then all tintColor for navigation bar and tool bar turns to be the blue color(the system blue color).

Comment: Can you post the code what you currently doing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set NavigationBar Tint Color in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521254/set-navigationbar-tint-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: @TussLászló The answer I have tried but doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because Apple assumes that we won't present more than 1 view controller and dims the background and ALL bar button items (not sure why) as default behavior to put focus on the frontmost view.

To fix this, you just need to force the tintAdjustmentMode to Normal on the app's window in DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
self.window.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarBGTile.png"] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionTopAttached barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where NavBarBGTile.png is a 1X1px tile image that in the color you want as navigation bar color

Also

```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Replace white with whatever you want

These lines should place at the begining of application launch

Comment: backgroundImage != tintColor

Comment: Truly, I'm talking about `tintColor` property, you can have a try as I described above. PS: I set modalPresentationStyle of the navigation controller to be 'UIModalPresentationCurrentContext' when I present it.

Comment: Also try this too [[UIToolBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
UIView *masterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 260)];
UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [self createPickerToolbarWithTitle:@"Surgeons"];
pickerToolbar.barTintColor= [UIColor blueColor];
pickerToolbar.translucent=YES;
[masterView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
[masterView addSubview:pickerViewObj];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.view = masterView;
viewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = viewController.view.frame.size;
self.popoverController =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController];
```